# Xcode 4 / iOS how to distribute an app for the App Store for anopther company?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, distribution

We have build an app. A company has bought an customized version of that app. We don't have access to the other companies Apple Developer account but the other company wants to distribute the app under their own name.
Is there any way we can hand over the app so that the other company can sign and distribute the app on the Apple app store without giving away our source code?

Thanks for any help.

**Update:**
I have found this site that may be the solution to my problem:
http://www.ketzler.de/2011/01/resign-an-iphone-app-insert-new-bundle-id-and-send-to-xcode-organizer-for-upload/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of cause you can. I am doing the same thing with more than 5 companies.

If they don't give you permission to login into their iOS Dev Center, ask them for their distribution certificate and distribution provisioning profile.

Just let them create these files and send them to you.

Then you can sign your App with their provisioning profile when you build a release version, and only send them the ".ipa" file to let them submit.

Here are steps to create these files, just in case they don't understand how to:

> To acquire the distribution certificate:
>
> Log in to the iOS Dev Center.
>
> Navigate to the iOS Provisioning Portal.
>
> Click the Distribution tab.
>
> Follow the instructions to create a new certificate that will be used
>   for distribution. The process is identical to that which you used to
>   create your development certificate.
>
> After the certificate is issued, download the .cer file to your
>   computer. Create a P12 file from your private key and certificate.
>
> Once you have the distribution certificate, you will need to create a
>   distribution provisioning profile:
>
> Go to the Provisioning section of the iOS Provisioning Portal.
>
> Select the Distribution tab.
>
> Create a profile for the App Store distribution method.
>
> After the distribution provisioning profile is created, download the
>   .mobileprovision file to your computer. Keep this file in a handy
>   location for later.

Comment: If you feel this answer is useful, a vote up or select it as the correct answer is appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question is no....

It is not possible to upload file on Apple store without credentials on their account.

You can take a developer account permission and through that you can upload it to store..

Comment: Hi Prateek, thanks for your answer. The other company is uploading the app. So they need to re-sign the ipa.

Comment: @Marlon : Yes profile should be re-signed from profile they create for that application